# Devices can't find (and ping) each other on the same network (modem)

Tags: networking, router, ping

I have a D-link modem model DSL-2730U.
DHCP server is enabled and is set to provide IPs in range 192.168.1.33 to 192.168.1.255.

DCHP works well and here is a list of current connected devices:
[DHCP Clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdQYn.png)

Now the problem is I can't see any devices on my PC (located at 192.168.1.33)

Here is ARP results:
[ARP results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQlQN.png)

And here is ping results from my PC (.33) to my phone and other devices:
[Ping results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwmY5.png)

I also created a local server at port 19000 (192.168.1.33:19000) using Nodejs and I couldn't reach it through my phone... But when I connected the PC to mobile's Hotspot and also through USB tethering (to use mobile's internet on PC) and in both cases my phone could see the local server (on port 19000 of my PC).

It's not just my PC and also other devices couldn't find each other on the local network (at least the pairs that I checked.)
And now I'm getting crazy trying to find out why devices can't see each other on the network.

**Settings:**

On advanced Wireless settings User Isolation is off and Visibility is on:
[Advanced Wireless settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2nz9.png)

Here is local network settings on modem:
[Local network settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfHbL.png)

Here is Firewall settings on modem:
[Firewall settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgtjp.png)

And here is other settable options on modem that I have no clue what they are:
[Extra settings #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Ns1.png),
[Extra settings #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlrEa.png)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here is local network settings on modem:   ....  Can you initially uncheck the extra subnet and restart the router to see if that has any effect.

Comment: @John No results. Changed it to default values.

Comment: You may need to try a different router to test.

Comment: I did connected my PC to My Phone's Hotspot and I could ping them from both sides with ease... I just don't understand what is wrong with my modem

Comment: Try updating the firmware on your router and doing a hard reset to factory specifications.